# WARNING: Unable to find dependency

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, crystal-reports-2010

I have built an application with VB.net 2010 and framework 4 and I have installed crystal report too. whenever I try to create a setup, this warning appears :

> WARNING: Unable to find dependency
>   'BUSINESSOBJECTS.LICENSING.KEYCODEDECODER'
>   (Signature='692FBEA5521E1304' Version='13.0.2000.0') of assembly
>   'CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.dll'

this error shows when I install on other PCs .

Do you have any idea about this ?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you must to install Crystal Report 2010 on the client where you are running your application.

From msdn blog:

> Starting on Friday, April 16th, the beta version of Crystal Reports
>   for Visual Studio 2010 will be available as a separate download from
>   this site.  Just like when Crystal Reports was integrated into the 
>   Visual Studio installation, this download will continue to be free.

From: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vbteam/archive/2010/04/08/crystal-reports-for-visual-studio-2010.aspx?PageIndex=4

Take a look here: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vscrystalreports/thread/91f71ce2-e591-45a1-8bc2-0d61cd090117/